# Unable to call main function in VS 2022

Tags: c#, function, delegates, visual-studio-2022, program-entry-point

In VS 2022, the entry point of the code public static void main no longer exist.

I was trying to implement a simple delegate but no output is shown on the console:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public delegate void SomeMethodPointer(); // delegate definition

    public class MyClassDel
    {
        // function which I am trying to call through a delegate
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the function");
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        // created this here as program,cs is empty in my console app
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initialize the delegate with a method reference
            SomeMethodPointer obj = new SomeMethodPointer(DoSomething); 

            // Call the delegate
            obj.Invoke(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot be compiled.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your code editor without personal privacy?(include code and break point position)

Answer (score 1):

In `Main()`, you need to create an INSTANCE of your class `MyClassDel`, and then make your delegate point to the the `DoSomething()` method of that particular instance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClassDel mcd = new MyClassDel();
    SomeMethodPointer obj = new SomeMethodPointer(mcd.DoSomething);
    obj.Invoke(); // Call the delegate
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Alternatives...

(1) Make `DoSomething()` a static method in class `MyClassDel`:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public delegate void SomeMethodPointer(); // delegate definition
    
    public class MyClassDel
    {
        public static void DoSomething() // function which i am trying to call through delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the function");
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeMethodPointer obj = new SomeMethodPointer(MyClassDel.DoSomething); // Initialize the delegate with a method reference
            obj.Invoke(); // Call the delegate
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

(2) Make `DoSomething()` a static method in class `Program`:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public delegate void SomeMethodPointer(); // delegate definition

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeMethodPointer obj = new SomeMethodPointer(DoSomething); // Initialize the delegate with a method reference
            obj.Invoke(); // Call the delegate
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void DoSomething() // function which i am trying to call through delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the function");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: the execution is not coming to the main function. I am using vs2022. how to find where the execution goes

Comment: the program executes without an error ..but the function is not being called. the debugger is also not hit ...

Comment: Are you sure it's not running? Note that I put `Console.ReadLine();` as the LAST line in `Main()`. Without that the console simply disappears too quickly for you to see the output...